# Networking: Whether my local network resources are exposed under carrier grade NAT?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I am under Carrier Grade NAT. I have a network setup in home where there are many systems connected to network. All these systems have file sharing enabled. Also there are other resources being shared like printers, NAS. Whether is it possible for my ISP or other user of the same ISP able to view my files or access my local resources as all users will form a local network to ISP?

I am pretty sure that if ISP is not using carrier grade NAT then only way for outsider to access local resouces is through port forwarding.

Can someone explain on how things would be under Carrier Grade NAT?.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

> as all users will form a local network to ISP?

They already do, even without CGNAT.

NAT does not change the way routers work and it doesn't change the way firewalls work. When you connect a router to your ISP, it doesn't matter what type of address it receives – it still behaves as a router, relaying packets between between two separate networks. The "LAN" interface of the router will have its own address prefix separate from the "WAN" interface, and the router will have a firewall allowing connections only in one direction, and so on.

Literally, the *only* thing that's different is that your router won't have a public address.

Comment: So unless I have port forwarding or something similar is set up, the router firewall wont allow access to local resources? Also I could see options top turn off firewall in router admin page. If I turn off does this mean others would be able to acces the local resources?

Comment: Well, yes and no. It would be kinda possible but still difficult (because your LAN subnet still uses private addresses, and other people don't have any routes towards it, and most ISPs actually have protections against this). It's also the same with or without CGNAT. In all cases, others certainly won't see your fileserver names popping up in their "network" lists.